# Find the area inside the circle $r = 10 \sin \theta$ and above the line $r = 2 \csc \theta$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, area

[Function Plotter graph](https://functionplotter.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MSwiZXEiOiIyL3Npbih0aGV0YSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDgwY2MiLCJ0aGV0YW1pbiI6IjAiLCJ0aGV0YW1heCI6IjJwaSIsInRoZXRhc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MSwiZXEiOiIxMHNpbih0aGV0YSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDgwY2MiLCJ0aGV0YW1pbiI6IjAiLCJ0aGV0YW1heCI6IjJwaSIsInRoZXRhc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIi0xMy4zMTkwOTE3OTY4NzQ5OTUiLCIxMi4wNzE1MzMyMDMxMjQ5OTUiLCItMy44MTkzMzU5Mzc0OTk5OTgyIiwiMTEuODA1NjY0MDYyNDk5OTk2Il19XQ--):

---

[image]

---

I think the formula is

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (\text{outer})^2 - (\text{inner})^2 d\theta$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are [where they intersect](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10sinx+%3D+2cscx,+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+2pi) in $[0, 2\pi]$.

This is what I got based on that

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{x}^{\pi-x} (10 \sin \theta)^2 - (2 \csc \theta)^2 d\theta$$

where $x= \sin^{-1}(\frac {1}{\sqrt{5}} )$

Is that right?

Comment: You are right. But note that $r(\pi-\theta)=r(\theta)$ for both curves, which means they are symmetric to y-axis(as shown in the graph), so the upper limit can be $\pi/2$ instead. (more convenient to calculate)

Comment: @lcn oh thanks XD post as answer?

Comment: Not necessary, the most important thing is you know how to do now.

Comment: @lcn well I would like to show my gratitude by giving you rep

Answer (score 1):

We can do this all with classical geometry.

The region in question is a circle or radius 5 less a section of a circle with angle $2\cos^{-1} \frac 35$ plus 2 $3-4-5$ right triangles.

$25\pi - 25\cos^{-1} \frac 35 + 12$

Lets see if calculus gives us the same answer.

limits of integration.

$2\csc \theta = 10\sin \theta\\
\frac 15 = \sin^2 \theta\\
\sin\theta = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 5}$

$\frac 12\int_{\sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt 5}}^{\pi - \sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt 5}} (10\sin\theta)^2 - (2\csc\theta )^2\ d\theta\\
\frac 12\int_{\sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt 5}}^{\pi - \sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt 5}}  50(1-\cos2\theta) - 4\csc^2\theta\ d\theta\\
25 (\theta -\sin\theta\cos\theta) + 2\cot\theta |_{\sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt 5}}^{\pi - \sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt 5}}\\
25 \pi -50\sin^{-1}\frac {1}{\sqrt 5} +20 - 8 
$

Does $25 \cos^{-1} \frac 35 = 50 \sin^{-1} \frac 1{\sqrt5}?$

Indeed it does!

Set up in Cartesian

inside:

$x^2 + y^2 = 10 y$

above $y = 2$

$\int_2^{10} \sqrt {10y - y^2} dy$

Comment: But the integral expression you have is just rewritten polar to Cartesian?

Comment: You want to do this in cartesian?